# Extracting specific value from Json

Tags: jquery

I got the result as `[{"BlockRefHandle":"11B67"}]`.

How can we extract the data `11B67`?

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: getDatawithToken(params),
    dataType : 'json', // expecting json returned from server
    success: function (result) {
        alert("success");  
        if (result.d.length > 0) {
            // access first element 
            alert(result.d[0]);   
        }  
    }
});
```

Comment: Using JavaScript or c# ? The tags are confusing.

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the value you want by acccessing the property `BlockRefHandle`, like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: getDatawithToken(params),
    dataType : 'json', // expecting json returned from server
    success: function (result) {
        alert("success");  
        if (result.length > 0) {
            // access first element 
            alert(result[0].BlockRefHandle);   
        }  
    }
});
```